# Correlated slopes and intercepts in lme4

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have what I think is a simple question. I have run a simple linear mixed model using lme4. It is a random slopes and intercepts model and I am looking at how these intercepts (B0) and slopes (B1) vary among several treatment groups. The end result of this analysis will be an estimation of the effect of the treatments on B0 and B1, and one of the outputs of the model is the correlation between random effects (slopes and intercepts).

The question I have is this; suppose as a follow up to this mixed model, I was interested in how the RELATIONSHIP between slopes (B1) and intercepts (B0) varied between treatment groups. That is, I am interested in how (or if) the relationship between random effects (B0, B1) changes between treatment groups.

Is there a way to extract this information from my original analysis? Is the question I am asking missing the point? Any suggestions on further analysis would be welcome.